# Why does Peskin and Schroeder move normal ordering move outside a commutator?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, operators, commutator, wick-theorem

The equation trying to prove that Wick's theorem  by induction in P&S on page 90 implies that normal ordering can be moved outside a commutator (at least with a positive frequency field), which I just don't understand. It implies

$$[\phi_1^+,N(\phi_2\ldots\phi_m)] = N([\phi_1^+, \phi_2\ldots\phi_m]).$$

What am I missing here?

Comment: Did you find an answer to your question elsewhere?

Answer (score 1):

I assume you're referring to the line(s) which say

$$\phi_1^+N(\phi_2\cdots\phi_m) = N(\phi_2\cdots\phi_m)\phi_1^+ + [\phi_1^+,N(\phi_2\cdots\phi_m)]$$
$$=N(\phi_1^+\phi_2\cdots\phi_m) + N\big([\phi_1^+,\phi_2^-]\phi_3\cdots \phi_m + \phi _2[\phi_1^+,\phi_3^-]\phi_4\cdots\phi_m + \cdots\big)$$

The implication here is that $N(\phi_2\cdots\phi_m)\phi_1^+=N(\phi_1^+ \phi_2\cdots\phi_m)$.  This is simply because $\phi_1^+$ contains only annihilation operators, and so normal ordering puts it on the right hand side.

Comment: I'm referring to the second term, not the first. The first term absorbing $\phi_1^+$ makes sense.

Comment: @KPomykala The term with the commutators, you mean?

Comment: Yup, the latter one.